# Process Explorer: Process Disk: Read/Write bytes not working?

Tags: windows, ssd, process-explorer, sysinternals

I like to find out which program using mostly my SSD.

On Windows 7 x64 machine in Process Explorer (opened as Administrator) double clicking on a process opens up the details of it. On the *Disk and Network* tab there is a *Disk I/O* conatiner which should show the disk usage, but it doesn't. To be fair it counts the *Other* writes, but *Reads* and *Writes* are zero.

[image]

I tries out the 64 and 32 bit versions too, same results.

Comment: It's highly unlikely Process Explorer is wrong. Use Process Monitor from SysInternals to find out what process is doing the disk I/O.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator, please explain it: I cannot find any I/O data about processes.

Comment: try processhacker: http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @magicandre1981: Wow... o_O Reading directly the program's memory impressed me. Disk I/O seems to be working. Cool stuff, I will use it hereinafter. Thanks!

Comment: I use ProcessHacker now all time. With plugins it is more powerful compared to ProcessExplorer

Comment: @magicandre1981, maybe you can answer my other question too: https://superuser.com/questions/1272065/i-o-write-or-disk-write-affects-the-ssd