# "I/O write" or "Disk write" affects the SSD?

Tags: windows, ssd, process-explorer, sysinternals, process-hacker

I like to find out which program using mostly my SSD.

I'm using [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) (in elevated mode) to get an overview of my SSD usage and find the programs whose using it mostly. To test the mesurement, I copied about 1GB data in Total Commander and checked the values in Process Hacker.

[image]

I thougth that disk write will be around 1GB, but it's not: only 24.48MB whereas I/O write bytes is 1.19GB. How can it be? If "Disk write" doesn't means "Writing data to the SSD" then what's the purpose of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found the answer on [Process Hacker forum](https://wj32.org/processhacker/forums/viewtopic.php?t=320#p1260):

> They're different concepts. If a process writes to a named pipe, that's I/O, but it has nothing to do with the disk(s) on your computer. Similarly if a process does I/O on a file, the contents don't have to be written out to disk immediately.

So I/O includes every data transfer, while disk read/write can be inacurate.

Comment: Loosely relevant: RAM usage of programs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984186/what-is-private-bytes-virtual-bytes-working-set